# how to configure tls on Delphi TRestClient component

Tags: android, ios, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

Helo,

I typed the code as follows and this code works well. 
By using an https connection I hope that the Packet Data received cannot be read by applications such as Wireshark or the Packet Capture application on Android.

how do you configure the client side?

this my code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyCompletionHandler: TCompletionHandler;
  MyErrorCompletionHandler: TCompletionHandlerWithError;
begin
  ShowLoadingIndicator(Self, True);
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://reqres.in/';
  RESTClient1.RaiseExceptionOn500 := False;
  RESTClient1.SecureProtocols := [THTTPSecureProtocol.TLS12];
  RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'api/users';

  MyCompletionHandler := procedure
      var i: Integer;
          tJson: TJSONValue;
    begin
      Label1.Text := 'Complete!';
      Memo1.Lines.Append('Header: ');
      for I := 0 to RESTResponse1.Headers.Count-1 do
        Memo1.Lines.Append(RESTResponse1.Headers.Strings[I]);
      Memo1.Lines.Append('');
      Memo1.Lines.Append('Body:');
      tJson := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(RESTResponse1.Content);
      try
        memo1.Lines.Append(REST.Json.TJson.Format(tJson));
      finally
        FreeAndNil(tJson);
      end;
      HideLoadingIndicator(Self);
    end;

  MyErrorCompletionHandler := procedure(AObject: TObject)
    begin
      Label1.Text := 'Error!';
      HideLoadingIndicator(Self);
    end;

  RESTRequest1.ExecuteAsync(MyCompletionHandler, True, True, MyErrorCompletionHandler);
end;
```

[result packet capture using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liB9u.png)
 [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture)

and this simple apps made with firemonkey:
[Simple Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p58EY.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @nolaspeaker how do you configure the client side? it is in the beginning.

Comment: What does "configure" mean?

Comment: [Configure](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/configure) "To set up or arrange something in such a way that it is ready for operation for a particular purpose, or to someone's particular liking", so in this case, how to set-up the TRESTClient to be able to operate using TLS.

Comment: @GolezTrol what makes you think there is anything to configure, besides the `SecureProtocols`?

Comment: sorry for my confusing question, the point is I want to make the packet data unreadable by the sniffer and I think by doing the correct configuration on TRESTClient will make it happen

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't know. In the past extra dll's were needed for SSL. I'd assume that is still the case, but Embarcadero's documentation on this property is -as usual- non-existent, and OP apparently misses some step. The question may not be great, but seems fair, so my response was mainly aimed at nolaspeaker who seems to want to cover it in riddles.